# Let $A$ a conmutative ring, such that $A$ such that $1_A \not \in A$. Let $k \in A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ a conmutative ring, such that $A$ such that $1_A \not \in A$. Let $k \in A$. Prove that $\langle k \rangle = \{ak + nk : a\in A \text{ and } n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

I don't have a clear idea of how to solve this problem. Can someone help me with a hint?

Comment: What properties define $\langle k \rangle$?

Answer (score 3):

$\langle k\rangle$ is the smallest ideal of $A$ that contains $k$.

Any ideal that contains $k$ must contain $ak+k+\ldots+k=ak+mk$ and $ak+(-k)+\ldots+(-k)=ak-mk$,

so $S=\{ak + nk : a\in A \text{ and } n\in\mathbb{Z}\}\subset\langle k\rangle$.

Furthermore, $k\in S$.

All you have to check is that $S$ is an ideal.

For all $a_1,a_2\in A$ and for all $n_1,n_2\in\mathbb{Z}$,

- $(a_1 k+n_1 k)+(a_2 k+n_2 k)=(a_1+a_2)k+(n_1+n_2)k$;
- $a_1(a_2k+nk)=(a_1 a_2+na_1)k$;

both are easy to verify.